# How to divide monthly totals by the seasonal monthly ratio in R

Tags: r

I am trying de-seasonalize my data by dividing my monthly totals by the average seasonality ratio per that month. I have two data frames. avgseasonality that has 12 rows of the average seasonality ratio per month. The problem is since the seasonality ratio is the ratio of each month averaged only has 12 rows and the ordertotal data frame has 147 rows.

```
deseasonlize <- transform(avgseasonalityratio, deseasonlizedtotal = 
df1$OrderTotal / avgseasonality$seasonalityratio)
```

This runs but it does not pair the months appropriately. It uses the first ratio of april and runs it on the first ordertotal of december.

```
> avgseasonality
       Month seasonalityratio
1      April        1.0132557
2     August        1.0054602
3   December        0.8316988
4   February        0.9813396
5    January        0.8357475
6       July        1.1181648
7       June        1.0439899
8      March        1.1772450
9        May        1.0430667
10  November        0.9841149
11   October        0.9595041
12 September        0.8312318

> df1
# A tibble: 157 x 3
 DateEntLabel        OrderTotal `d$Month`
  <dttm>                   <dbl> <chr>    
 1 2005-12-01 00:00:00    512758. December 
 2 2006-01-01 00:00:00    227449. January  
 3 2006-02-01 00:00:00    155652. February 
 4 2006-03-01 00:00:00    172923. March    
 5 2006-04-01 00:00:00    183854. April    
 6 2006-05-01 00:00:00    239689. May      
 7 2006-06-01 00:00:00    237638. June     
 8 2006-07-01 00:00:00    538688. July     
 9 2006-08-01 00:00:00    197673. August   
10 2006-09-01 00:00:00    144534. September
# ... with 147 more rows
```

I need the ordertotal and ratio of each month respectively. The calculations would for each month respectively be such as (december) 512758/0.8316988 = 616518.864762 The output for the calculations would be in their new column that corresponds with the month and ordertotal. Please any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to `merge()` your data first, then do the operation. You can use R base `merge()` function, though I will show here using the `tidyverse` `left_join()` function. I see that one of your columns has a strange name `d$Month`, renameing this to Month will simplify the merge!

Reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df_1 <-  data.frame(Month = c("Jan", "Feb"), seasonalityratio = c(1,2))
df_2 <-  data.frame(Month = rep(c("Jan", "Feb"),each=2), OrderTotal = 1:4)


df_1 %>% 
  left_join(df_2, by = "Month") %>% 
  mutate(eseasonlizedtotal = OrderTotal / seasonalityratio)
#>   Month seasonalityratio OrderTotal eseasonlizedtotal
#> 1   Jan                1          1               1.0
#> 2   Jan                1          2               2.0
#> 3   Feb                2          3               1.5
#> 4   Feb                2          4               2.0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I did not think about doing it this way but it worked perfectly. I appreciate your time and learned about using joins. I was not aware we could join the data like this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I see this is the first time, you can accept satisfying answers by clicking the green mark, as well as using the up arrow. Welcome to the forum!

Comment: I need more points to use the up arrow. But i got the green check mark!